# Not well formed error in firefox when using getScript

Tags: jquery, firefox

I do many search in stackoverflow and google, but I cannot found a logical way !

I use getScript to load a js file, I get "Not Well Formed" error in Firefox error console.
I trying to comment all lines of my code in js file, and again I get that error !

```
Timestamp: 04/25/2012 02:02:32 PM
Error: not well-formed
Source File: file:///G:/ct/main/main.js?_=1335346352617
Line: 1, Column: 1
Source Code:
/*
```

I use $.ajax too, I get exactly that error.

Note: my included JS code work without any problem and everything is OK (when my code is not commented), but I want to know why my user should get this error in Firefox ?!

Sorry for my bad English.

EDIT:

```
var ulWidth = 0; 
$('.carousel_links ul li').each(function(){ 
  ulWidth += $(this).outerWidth(); 
}); 

$('.carousel_links ul').css({ 
   'width' : ulWidth+'px' 
});
```

UPDATE:

I found this way:
[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

I use this and I think this way is better than `$.getScript` because I don't get any error and all of my JavaScript code work fine.

Comment: ...Well what's the code?

Comment: @Jivings I wrote a jQuery code, as I said, my jquery code work fine, for example if I delete all lines in JS file and add just `alert('OK');` the Alert box will show and everything is ok but I got that error again

Comment: Show your loadScript code then. More information is needed here before an answer can be deduced.

Comment: @Jivings this is my JS code : `var ulWidth = 0;
$('.carousel_links ul li').each(function(){
 ulWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
});
$('.carousel_links ul').css({
 'width' : ulWidth+'px'
});
`

Comment: The code that's being loaded?

Comment: @Jivings Yes this code is in my js file and load without any problem

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this. Are you sure you've provided as much information as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be do do with the `mime` type of the requested document.

If it's running on your server, make sure that it knows what to do with `.js` files. It should return `text/javascript`.

If not then it should definitely work when requested like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "filename.js");
req.overrideMimeType("text/javascript");
req.send(null);
```